# How to add a close button to a bootstrap hamburger menu

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to add a close "X" button to my bootstrap hamburger menu:

'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary') ); ?>

Here's my site as is:

https://thesavvy-retiree.com/

I've scoured the internet for a solution with no joy.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary') ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the answer you asked for, but why not use the bootstrap hamburger icon for opening **and closing**? This is the default behaviour for a bootstrap hamburger menu. From what I've seen on your website, the menu that will popup is currently blocking the hamburger icon so you can't close it.

You could add more margin to the menu so it isn't blocking anymore:

```
.menu-primary-container { margin-top: 72px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this issue, this is what worked in the end:

```
.menu-primary-container {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
z-index: -1;
}

#logo-image {
    z-index: -2;
}
```

}